# $ \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x\partial y} = 0 $, then $ T = ? $

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Can we characterize all distributions $T \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^2) $ with
the following property of distribution derivatives ?
$$ \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x\partial y} = 0 $$
For functions it just looks like $ f(x) +g(y) + c $, but having trouble figuring out the general case. Any hints or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @Tomás : I don't know why the downvotes, and my advice to you is not to worry about them. +1 from me

Comment: Maybe the downvoters didn't notice that the question is about distributions and not smooth functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider two operators from $\mathcal D(\mathbb R^2)$ to $\mathcal D(\mathbb R)$, defined as follows. For a test function $\phi:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$,

- $(I_x \varphi)(y) = \int_{\mathbb R}\varphi(x,y)\,dx$
- $(I_y \varphi)(x) = \int_{\mathbb R}\varphi(x,y)\,dy$

The adjoint of $I_x$ maps $\mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$ into $\mathcal D'(\mathbb R^2)$, which is a fancy way of saying that some distributions $T\in \mathcal D'(\mathbb R^2)$ can be written in the form $S\circ I_x$  for some $S\in \mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$. These are [precisely the distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/448906) that satisfy $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x}=0$.

Since $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial y}$ is of the above type, we have $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial y} = S\circ I_x$ for some $S\in \mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$. Similarly, $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x} = R\circ I_y$ for some $R\in \mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$. The distribution 
$$T- S\circ I_x-R\circ I_y$$
has both $x$- and $y$- derivatives equal to zero, and therefore is [constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10563). The constant can be incorporated into either $S$ or $R$, leading to the answer
$$T = S\circ I_x+R\circ I_y$$
with arbitrary $S,R\in \mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Okay, good enough as a generalization. Thanks !